# Interpretation of Market Price of Volatility Risk

Tags: option-pricing, financial-markets, market-model

In option pricing with market model equipped with stochastic volatility, there are numerous times mentioning "market price of volatility risk" without even define or give any explanation regarding the term.

I also want to ask, what is the interpretation of zero market price of volatility risk?

Please help me understand "market price of volatility risk" and it would be appreciated if the explanation supported by scientific literature. Thank you!